# How to map sub-folder to a virtual host in Apache or htaccess in react js

Tags: reactjs, apache, .htaccess, redirect, next.js

I have a React JS /Next JS website (eg: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) which calls images which we have been mapped to another virtual domain (eg: assets.example.com) since we did not want to have those hundreds of pictures in the react project/public folder.

This means that in output/view source, the links for the images come like:
http://assets.example.com/picture1.jpg etc.)

However, now SEO gets affected as Google considers the "assets" sub-domain different than the "www".

Ideally, we would like to have images called from "www", eg: http://www.example.com/picture1.jpg, but internally they should be picked up from another folder or virtual domain.

Is this possible using htaccess or apache or something with some react plugin/library?

We tried rewriting the URL but did not work. We tried calling images via some API (returned via API) but that slows/loads the solution. We have hundreds of pictures called from the website (product catalogue)

**Edit**: Another idea could if [www.example.com/foo](http://www.example.com/foo) can point to foo.example.com internally but Address Bar/URL still shows [www.example.com/foo](http://www.example.com/foo) to users.

**Solution**:
Found the solution. Sharing the same for benefit of others:

```
<Virtualhost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
.
.
  <Location "/foo/">
    ProxyPass "https://foo.example.com/"
  </Location>
.
.
.
</Virtualhost>
```

This passes http://www.example.com/foo to internally call as http://foo.example.com

Comment: Have you tried RewriteRule, something like this in your .htaccess file, RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^example.com(.*)\.jpg$ assets.example.com/$1.jpg [NC]

Answer (score 0):

In the DNS console of your domain registration, register and point `exemple.com` to your server and `www.exemple.com` as an alias of `exemple.com` (just to make easy config).
And then, with Apache, you can create a proxy that masks all calls, like:

```
<Virtualhost *:443>
ServerName exemple.com/images

ProxyPass / https://images.exemple.com/
ProxyPassReverse / https://exemple.com/images
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: But that would still mean 2 sub-domains, www and www.subdomain. What I am looking for is that www.example.com/foo should point to foo.example.com but show www.example.com/foo in URL address bar (something like masking)

Comment: Now I understand. Sorry, I edited the answer. Does that help you?

Comment: Thank you, your answer gave me a direction and I was able to solve it. I have edited my question to reflect the same.